# Roomba stops responding to commands on the OI

Tags: irobot-create, roomba

So I just received my roomba create 2. I have managed to read and send commands to the roomba using the OI and an Arduino. I also got it to move using the USB cable provided by iRobot and the tethered app on windows. However after one or two min it either stop responding to any commands, or just turns off. If the last command was to move forward, it will continue to that. If it wasn't moving, then clicking on any of the buttons on the app will not make it do anything. I haven't figured out how to get the firmware version. Any help or guidance will be deeply appreciated.d

Thank you!
Sep

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem may be the standard timeout when it is running on the battery

[image: Roomba sleeping on battery mode]

Please note that this is not the same as the issue I described needing a firmware update while sleeping on the dock.

Frank

Comment: Thank you for the reply. So I saw a comment from Steve who is the iRobot Engineer saying something about "There is a bug in the implementation of sleep/wakeup on Create 2 which was fixed in release-3.8.2 for robots with an older processor, or release-stm32-3.7.7 for robots with a newer processor. " My firmware is 3.7.5 and it crashes even if I use the app on windows they offer. I have also tried putting in full mode where after 2 min it just shuts itself down. I will try to implement the BRC pulse regularly and see if it helps.